# Regular Expression - Remove all special characters except alphanumeric and accents

Tags: python, regex

How is possible to remove all special characters except alphanumeric and accents?

I tried something like:

```
text = 'abcdeáéí.@# '
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôÂÊÎÔãõÃÕçÇ: ]', ' ', text)
```

But I hadn't success. the following expression is valid to allow just alphanumeric but not to accents:

```
tmp = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9: ]', '', x)
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your text a unicode string `text = u'abcdeáéí.@# '` and make sure your pattern is able to accept unicode characters as well `re.sub(u'[^a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôÂÊÎÔãõÃÕçÇ: ]', ' ', text)`

With this combination, I get `u'abcde\xe1\xe9\xed    '` as a result (where `\xe1` etc. are escape codes for the accent characters in `text`

There's no need for `r` in front of the pattern if you aren't escaping any characters. It's there so you can write things like `r'\d\w'` instead of `'\\d\\w'`

Comment: What version of Python is this? From what I remember, Python 2's regex engine doesn't support unicode.

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 16 2012, 13:05:29) 
[GCC 4.5.3] on linux2

Comment: That's odd. I made the exact same changes and the final string comes out without accented characters: `print re.sub(u'[^a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôÂÊÎÔãõÃÕçÇ: ]'.encode('utf-8'), ' ', u'abcdeáéí.@# ')`. The script doesn't run without `.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: I get `abcde` with your snippet. However
`>>> print re.sub(u'[^a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôÂÊÎÔãõÃÕçÇ: ]', ' ', u'abcdeáéí.@# ')` results in `abcdeáéí`